# Referring one variable from another variable in same scala class

Tags: scala, lazy-loading

I have a scala class like below

```
    class Event {
      val query: String =
        s"""
           | Created >= "2020-01-01" AND ${event_filter}
           |  """
          .stripMargin
    
      val event_filter: String =
        s"""
           |  event= 'CreateTask'
           |  """
          .stripMargin
    }
```

And then I have a below testing class to test Event query.

```
    class EventTest extends FunSuite{
       test ("testing event query") {
         val obj:Event = new Event()
         assert(obj.query == "Created >= \"2020-01-01\" AND event= \"CreateTask\" ") 
       }
    }
```

While running the test case I am getting a mismatch between actual and expected value. I am getting obj.query like this "Created >= "2020-01-01" AND null".

Any idea why event_filter is getting populated as null ? Is it because the variables are lazily loaded ?

Comment: Because fields are evaluated in order. The easiest solution is to move `event_filter` before `query`.

Comment: Ah! make sense. Thanks.

Comment: another possibility is to use `lazy val`s

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, this is a problem with initialisation order. You can fix this by re-ordering the `val`s or making the first value `lazy val` so it is not evaluated until it is first used, which will be after the second is initialised.

```
class Event {
  val event_filter: String =
    s"""
       |  event= 'CreateTask'
       |  """
      .stripMargin

  val query: String =
    s"""
       | Created >= "2020-01-01" AND ${event_filter}
       |  """
      .stripMargin

}
```

or

```
class Event {
  lazy val query: String =
    s"""
       | Created >= "2020-01-01" AND ${event_filter}
       |  """
      .stripMargin

  val event_filter: String =
    s"""
       |  event= 'CreateTask'
       |  """
      .stripMargin
}
```